# How to load static file of a model in a html templates

Tags: django, templates, static

I have a static file structure like this -----> static/images/article_images/images.png

here's my *settings.py*

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    # '/css/',
    # 'images/article_image/',
]
```

here's what I tried:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
 {% load static %} ---> i have this in my base.html
    <div class="article-block" method="GET">
        {% for article in articles %}

        <!-- <img src="{{ article.image }}" alt="Article image"> -->
        <img src="{% static '{{article.image}}' %}" alt="Article image">
        <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

here's my model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

def article_image_path(instance, filename):
    return f"static/images/article_image/{filename}"

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to=article_image_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: show us model related to this image

Comment: It means you want to show uploaded images

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I've updated my model with the image.

Comment: you can;t use static settings for to show uploaded image. you should use media setting instead

Comment: @ManojTolagekar can you elaborate more?? do I need to change upload directory path??

Comment: ok will tell you how to do this

Comment: checkout my answer and try that

Comment: Files uploaded into ImageField are **media** files, not **static**. They need different approaches which are both well described in Django docs.

Answer (score 0):

Static files are not bound by `model`. In your templates you should be using:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %} ---> include this line after extends in every template that require static files.
 {% block content %}
 
<div class="article-block" method="GET">
    {% for article in articles %}

    <img src="{{ article.image }}" alt="Article image"/> <-- Use this if image is stored inside article model

    <img src="{% static 'images/image_name.png' %}"   alt="Article image"/> <--use this if your image is stored statically
    
    <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: my images is stored inside the article model with custom path. I've updated my question with the model. I tried both ways, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `article_image_path` function from models.

And then, add `path name` in model field image directly.

For ex:

```
image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='images/') #path added here. uploaded images will store in this images folder. images folder will be created inside media folder automatically in your project root.
```

And in **settings.py** file just add media settings:

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

In your main `urls.py` file, just add this:

```
+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**EX:**

```
urlpatterns = [
 
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) #Added here
```

Note: don't forget to migrate the model after making changes in image field.